# Can kubeadmin user create resources past the ClusterResourceQuota hard limit?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, quota

I have the following `ClusterResourceQuota` created in my openshift cluster:

```
apiVersion: quota.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: eight-load-balancer-quota
  resourceVersion: "1158006"
spec:
  quota:
    hard:
      services.loadbalancers: "8"
  selector:
    labels:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: managed.openshift.io/storage-pv-quota-exempt
        operator: DoesNotExist
```

However I am able to create more than eight loadbalancers in my cluster (logged in as kubeadmin) is that as expected?

```
oc --kubeconfig=... describe AppliedClusterResourceQuota
Name:       eight-load-balancer-quota
Created:    2 days ago
Labels:     <none>

Label Selector: !managed.openshift.io/storage-pv-quota-exempt
AnnotationSelector: map[]
Resource        Used    Hard
--------        ----    ----
services.loadbalancers  10  8
```

I am not seeing any reference to this situation in the [docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/admin_guide/multiproject_quota.html).

Comment: What version of Openshift are you using?

Comment: @PjoterS it is 4.x

Comment: Are you sure those LB are working? What is `oc get svc --all-namespaces`? LB obtain any IP Address? Can you curl them?